# Replacing Numbers with text in php

Tags: php, if-statement

So my taslk is to program two numbers randomly (for example 0 and 1) and then replace the numbers with "Hello" and "bye". I've done the generating it rendomly part, but now I'm struggling with the replacing Part. It would be cool If the solution would be by using "if" and "else"
Here's what i've done so far,

thank you in advance

```
<?php

    $zaehler = 0;

while($zaehler < 10)
    {

    
    echo mt_rand(0, 1);
    
    if(0)
    {
        echo "bye" ;
    }
    
    else (1) ;
    {
        echo "hello" ;
    }
    $zaehler++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to read up on your `if` and `else` syntax. Your `if` will never execute because "0" is never true.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, just use a comparison statement

e.g.

if($result==0) { // do something;} else {// do another thing;  }

(the $result will only be either 0 or 1, so just use one if-then-else)

```
<?php

    $zaehler = 0;

 while($zaehler < 10){

    $result=mt_rand(0, 1);
    echo $result;

      if($result==0) {
         echo "bye" ;
         } else {
          echo "hello" ;
      }

    $zaehler++;
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i just saw your post,

First, you need to assign mt_rand to a variable.
Afer your statement IF isnt correct, you need to evaluate something like this $i === 0
And about your else you need an else if, so you can take a look to this code ;)

```
$idx = 0;

while ($idx < 10) {
    $random_int = mt_rand(0, 1);
    if ($random_int === 0) {
        echo "bye\r\n";
    } else if ($random_int === 1) {
        echo "hello\r\n";
    }
    $idx++;
}
```

Comment: _"you need an else if"_ - That's not true though. `mt_rand(0, 1)` will only return either `0` or `1` so it's pretty safe to assume that if `$random_int` is not equal to `0`, it's definitely `1`.

Comment: It's was just to show how to manage his probleme because he put else (1) ;

Comment: ...and the simplest and cleanest solution to that specific issue would be to simply remove the `(1) ;` :-)